# javax.servlet.ServletException: PWC1232: Exceeded maximum depth for nested request dispatches: 20

Tags: eclipse, jsf, glassfish

I have created simple Java Dynamic Web project in Eclipse. I host my project on Glassfish 2.1.1. When I try open `p1.jsf` page in browser I got following error: 
`javax.servlet.ServletException: PWC1232: Exceeded maximum depth for nested request dispatches: 20`.

I have no idea how to correct this error...

Here is may `p1.jsf` definition:

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <%@ taglib prefix="f"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
 <%@ taglib prefix="h"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <title>Insert title here</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <f:view>
  <h:outputLabel value="outputLabel"></h:outputLabel>
 </f:view>
 </body>
 </html>
```

My web.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
   <display-name>web4</display-name>
   <welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
     <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
     <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
     <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
     <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
     <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   <servlet>
     <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

My faces-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd"
    version="1.2">

</faces-config>
```

Error details from Glassfish log:

```
PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet FacesServlet threw exception javax.servlet.ServletException: PWC1232: Exceeded maximum depth for nested request dispatches: 20
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:860)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:723)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:558)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:490)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:382)
 com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:410)
 com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.executePageToBuildView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:468)
 com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:140)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:110)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
 javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:427)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:873)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:723)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:558)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:490)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:382)
 com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:410)
 com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.executePageToBuildView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:468)
 com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:140)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:110)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
 javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:427)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:873)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:723)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:558)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:490)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:382)
 com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:410)
 com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.executePageToBuildView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:468)
 com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:140)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:110)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
 javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:427)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:873)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:723)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:558)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:490)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:382)
 com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:410)
 com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.executePageToBuildView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:468)
 com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:140)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:110)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
 javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. FacesServlet should be mapped on an `url-pattern` of `*.jsf` (or anything else other than `*.jsp`).
2. No `javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX` is needed in web.xml if you already use JSP. The JSP page itself must actually be named `pagename.jsp` (and thus **not** `pagename.jsf`, this is the root cause of the recursive forward calls).
3. Open the page in the webbrowser using the `*.jsf` suffix: `http://example.com/context/pagename.jsf` (and thus **not** by `pagename.jsp`, else you would get `RuntimeException: FacesContext not found`).

Answer (score 0):

This means that recursive internal forwards occur. A few things to observe:

- make sure you are accessing the page via the right suffix. i.e. `http://localhost:8080/app/p1.jsp`, and not `p1.page` - you have mapped the jsf suffix to be `.jsp`
- check your navigation rules in your faces-config.xml
- make sure you have the following context-param defined:

  ```
  <context-param>
      <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
      <param-value>.jsp</param-value>
  </context-param>
  ```

To summarize - the `javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX` determines the file extension under which the page are sought, and the `<url-pattern>` of the faces-servlet determines the way the jsf pages are accessed by clients (browsers)

Comment: I am accessing page via address http://localhost:18080/web1/p1.jsp. If I change page file name to p1.jsf and URL pattern to <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern> I still got the same problem. I have added faces-config.xml to the abowe question.

Comment: but is your file named p1.page ? If so, rename it to .jsp

Comment: No, file is was named p1.jsp. In post a have made mistake, sorry.

Comment: then define the context-param as mentioned in my updated answer

Comment: To sum up, I have (1) changed web page file name to p1.jsf, (2) changed in web.xml file URL patter *<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>* and (3) added to web.xml file *<context-param><param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name><param-value>.jsf</param-value></context-param>*. I have no navigation rules defined in faces-config.xml.

Unfortunately, I still got the same error... **Exceeded maximum depth for nested request dispatches.**

Comment: In previous comment point 2 should look like this (formatting issue): changed in web.xml file URL patter to <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>