# jboss-as-7.1.0.Final - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Header count exceeded allowed maximum: 128

Tags: jboss7.x, illegalstateexception

I am using  jboss-as-7.1.0.Final  as the server with Eclipse Kepler. I am trying to create a Spring+Maven+Hibernate Application. The deployment happens fine but when i try to access the page locally @ "localhost:8080/AppName" i get "This page can’t be displayed" message and the logs have following trace:

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) An exception or error occurred in the container during the request processing: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Header count exceeded allowed maximum: 128
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.MimeHeaders.createHeader(MimeHeaders.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.MimeHeaders.setValue(MimeHeaders.java:386) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.prepareResponse(Http11Processor.java:1582) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.action(Http11Processor.java:998) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:190) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.sendHeaders(Response.java:390) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:335) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.close(OutputBuffer.java:301) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.finishResponse(Response.java:479) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]

16:42:39,230 ERROR [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Error finishing response: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Header count exceeded allowed maximum: 128
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.MimeHeaders.createHeader(MimeHeaders.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.MimeHeaders.setValue(MimeHeaders.java:386) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.prepareResponse(Http11Processor.java:1582) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.action(Http11Processor.java:998) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:188) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.endRequest(InternalOutputBuffer.java:363) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.endRequest(Http11Processor.java:958) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:904) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]

16:42:39,262 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) An exception or error occurred in the container during the request processing: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Header count exceeded allowed maximum: 128
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.MimeHeaders.createHeader(MimeHeaders.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.MimeHeaders.setValue(MimeHeaders.java:386) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.prepareResponse(Http11Processor.java:1582) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.action(Http11Processor.java:998) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:190) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.sendHeaders(Response.java:390) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:335) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.close(OutputBuffer.java:301) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.finishResponse(Response.java:479) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]

16:42:39,276 ERROR [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Error finishing response: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Header count exceeded allowed maximum: 128
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.MimeHeaders.createHeader(MimeHeaders.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.MimeHeaders.setValue(MimeHeaders.java:386) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.prepareResponse(Http11Processor.java:1582) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.action(Http11Processor.java:998) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:188) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.endRequest(InternalOutputBuffer.java:363) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.endRequest(Http11Processor.java:958) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:904) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
```

I tried modifying the standalone.xml file by adding the following lines, but it did not work.

```
<system-properties>
        <property name="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.MAX_COUNT" value="50000"/>
    </system-properties>
```

I am not able to find any property file that controls this setting. Can somebody please suggest a solution?

Comment: Cant find a solution. Any takers?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

My problem was solved as i add the "faces-config.xml" to my web-inf folder.

Hope it helps!

Also take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992391/javax-servlet-servletexception-pwc1232-exceeded-maximum-depth-for-nested-reque)